# My solidity file wont compile and i dont know why. Its says parse error on mint function line

Tags: solidity, remix, mint, ide

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract deCent is ERC20 {

    constructor () public ERC20("deCent", "DCT") {
        _mint(msg.sender; 1000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals()))));
    }
}
```

the error is line 10 it says parse error

Comment: Too many closing brackets

Comment: Ok so remove one of ye brackets or patenthesis

Answer (score 1):

1. Differnt compiler version
2. 2 extra right brackets
3. Using ';' as a parameter separator instead of ','

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract deCent is ERC20 {

constructor () ERC20("deCent", "DCT") {
    _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals()));
}
}
```